# How to extract categories out of short text documents?

Tags: nlp, cluster-analysis, text-mining, topic-modeling

My data contains the answers to the open-ended question: what are the reasons for recommending the organization you work for?

I want to use an algorithm / technique that, using this data, learns the categories (i.e. the reasons) that occur most frequently, and that a new answer to this question can be placed in one of these categories automatically.

I initially thought of topic modeling (for example LDA), but the text documents are very short in this problem (mostly between the 1 and 10 words per document). Therefore, is this an appropriate method? Or are there other models that are suitable for this? Perhaps a cluster method?

Note: the text is in Dutch

Answer (score 1):

No, clustering will work even worse.

It can't do magic.

You'll need to put in additional information, such as *labels* to solve this problem - use **classification**.

Find the most common terms that clearly indicate one reason or another and begin labeling posts.